# git error: cannot handle https

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, https

when I tried to use git clone https://xxx I got the following error 
I don't handle protocol 'https' 
Could anyone please help me?

full message:

dementrock@dementrock-A8Se:~$ git clone https://git.innostaa.com/innostaa.git

Cloning into innostaa...

fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

dementrock@dementrock-A8Se:~$ git --version

git version 1.7.4

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you running? which version of git?

Comment: Could you paste your error message ? And output of git --version ?

Comment: Version 0.99.9i is _really_ old (2005 or so); it probably does not support https yet. You should consider upgrading to 1.7.something

Comment: same issue with `git version 1.7.6` ... any solutions? I guess the upgrade to newer version did not help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Version `0.99.9i` of `git` probably does not support `https` protocol.

Try to install a more recent version of `git`. The easiest solution would be to install it via `apt-get`:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install git
```

After that check that the correct version is used:

```
$ hash -r
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

If the returned string is not `/usr/bin/git`, then you have another older version of `git` in your `PATH` that is masking the more recent one. Remove it.

---

If you do not want to install `git` via `apt-get` or if you do not have administrator privilege on your machine, you can built it from source. You can download them from git [website](http://git-scm.com/download), and compilation should be as simple as:

```
$ tar -xvfj git-1.7.4.2.tar.bz2
$ cd git-1.7.4.2
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/install
$ make && make install
```

After that, you'll have to add `$HOME/install/bin` to your `PATH`.

```
$ hash -r
$ PATH="$HOME/install/bin:${PATH}"
$ git --version
git version 1.7.4.2
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the PATH to update my git but the problem's still there; now the version is 1.7.4 and I got the error
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Comment: @dementrock: You didn't by any chance build git with one prefix, `make install` it there, then move it somewhere else, did you?

Comment: same issue with `git version 1.7.6` ...  were you able to clone via https? Above you show git version not successful clone via https ....

Answer (score 12):

Fixed this problem for Git 1.7.9 on Windows. Seemed to happen with many GIT instantiations on Windows. Had to do with the url not being properly escaped in the command line.

Solution:  Put the git repository URL in single quotes 'https://.......'

Comment: This also fixed it for me with Git 1.7.1 on linux.

Comment: Also, fixed it for me but I had to use double quotes. I was using from within Cygwin.

Comment: Double quotes worked for me with `git version 2.6.4.windows.1`

Comment: Also for me with Windows 7 and Git 2.10.1.windows.1 only double quotes worked!

Comment: worked for me with Cygwin, also had to amend the url in `.git/config`.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem but the reason was in my configuration of my .git. I changed config file as follows:

## .git/config

```
enter code here[remote "heroku"]
        url = git@heroku.com:rocky-bayou-4315.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

rocky-bayou-4315 is my heroku application that has been created by `$ heroku create` command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to "fetch upstream". I solved it by getting the Git-read only address instead of the https.

details:
I had a forked repository that needed updated from its original repo. Using github's help I added a remote upstream and tried to fetch it.

I then went to Git-hub and where I usually get the address of the the repo I clicked on the "Git-read only" button and got a new URL. I removed my past upstream and added another one with the new URL, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this problem with git 1.7.9 on cygwin.
Using the double quotes "" to wrap the https URL can solve my problem.

eg:

git clone "https://github.com/joyent/node.git"