# not able to push to heroku

Tags: heroku

I am a complete new bie to heroku
I just installed heroku toolbar and performed the below operation

```
$ heroku create
Creating pure-oasis-4419... done, stack is cedar
http://pure-oasis-4419.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:pure-oasis-4419.git
$ heroku create --stack cedar
Creating mighty-stream-7975... done, stack is cedar
http://mighty-stream-7975.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:mighty-stream-7975.git
$ git push heroku master
fatal: I don't handle protocol 'git@heroku.com:https'
```

Can any one please tell me why i am getting this error.

I also tried

```
git remote -v
```

Still I get

```
fatal: I don't handle protocol 'git@heroku.com:https'
```

I am sure i have a mistake somewhere. Could any one help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

- git pull the source code to your device.
- start working on the code. Or just rewrite them with yours.
- git add .
- git commit -m "commit message"
- git push

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because of your Git version. Try using the latest one as advised in older question [git error: cannot handle https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500247/git-error-cannot-handle-https)