# Accidentally set "remote.master.url", cannot get rid of it anymore?

Tags: git, version-control

Yesterday, I needed to change the remote URL of a repository as I had just set up Bitbucket to use SSH keys and wanted to switch from HTTPS to SSH.

I accidentally used **master** instead of **origin** when pointing to the repo's remote address, like so:

```
git remote add master git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrepo.git
```

when I should have used (and later did use):

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrepo.git
```

I checked git config to see if I had accidentally "broken" something and discovered the following two lines in there that aren't part of my other repositories as far as I could see (otherwise, they basically all look the same):

```
remote.master.url=git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrepo.git
remote.master.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/master/*
```

Now I'm somewhat confused. Isn't **origin** usually a shortcut/alias for my remote repository and **master** the one for my local repository? (Or maybe the main *branch* of my local repo? I never really work with different branches, so I usually only have one.) Or does **remote master** stand for the main branch in my remote repository? I.e. have I told git I have a remote master branch to differentiate it from other branches (which don't actually exist!)?

Unfortunately, **remote.master.url** doesn't turn up many Google results. It's mentioned once in this Stackoverflow thread: [What is "git remote add ..." and "git push origin master"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617211/what-is-git-remote-add-and-git-push-origin-master/5617684#5617684), but that thread doesn't give any explanation on how to remove it again either.

I tried to get rid of **remote.master.url** by doing this:

```
git remote set-url --delete master git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrepo.git
```

but that only resulted in a **fatal: Will not delete all non-push URLs** error message of which I have no idea what it means. (There's only one Google result for it, which is this other Stackoverflow thread, which doesn't deal with the error message itself: [fatal: I don't handle protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375402/fatal-i-dont-handle-protocol). Side note: too bad I don't have enough reputation to let user1888797 know he can retrieve the config file with `git config --list`.)

Is there some way to "reset" **remote.master.url**?
Or can it not be changed once it's set?
Should I just ignore it?
Might it lead to more confusion later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to rename it:

```
git remote rename master origin
```

> Or does remote master stand for the main branch in my remote repository?

No, here '`master`' is just the name of a remote, it is a key referring to a value (the remote url).

If remote `origin` still exists, then:

```
git remote remove master
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrepo.git
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! (origin still existed, so I tried the other two commands and they worked.) Still don't understand all the theory behind it but the two remote.master lines in my config file are gone. (;

Comment: @Kay Great! It is just a string being used as a shortcut for a remote url.